# Play! Java: pushing message from streams through Websockets

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, reactive-streams

We would like to push messages received through Kafka streams through to the client using websockets.

Our initial thought was to use Play! framework with Java for providing the HTTP interface and Akka for reactive stream processing and pushing the messages through Play's Iteratee, but Iteratee api seems not available for Play! Java. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I would not start with Iteratee's because the Play team is trying to move towards akka streams.

Comment: Move made already? Which version of play am I to look for?

Comment: Version 2.5 right?